# Google Sheets: Pop up message when a specific value is entered in a column

Tags: google-sheets, popup, popupwindow

This is my first go at creating something in Apps Script for Google Sheets and I'm a bit stuck/overwhelmed.  In the reading I've done I think what I'm attempting is rather basic.  I'm just not getting to the solution, so I need a nudge...

Need:
I have a sheet that is tracking equipment that is checked out and returned to a central area.
The sheet has multiple pages with identical layouts.

On each page I have one column where (3) different options can be chosen from a dropdown list.
IN, OUT, and UNAVAILABLE

For each of the (3) entry options, I would like a popup message to appear when the entry is changed.

So in the range of F2:F100, if the entry is changed to "OUT" from "IN" I would like a pop-up to appear with a message of "Clear all fields to the right." and an "OK" button.

I have found a lot of examples to make a pop up when ANY field is changed, or when a sheet is opened.  I'm stuck on limiting these pop-ups to only select fields/ranges/pages

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

You can refer to this sample script below that runs via [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger, where the pop-up message will only run [if](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) any selected cell is under column F & if that cell's value was changed to "OUT" on any sheet on a spreadsheet file:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //Check if selected cell is in column F (or col #6) was changed to "OUT"
  if(ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 6 & ss.getRange(ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()).getValue() == "OUT"){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Clear all fields to the right.');
  }
}
```

If ever you need to add more conditions like if you only want to run the script to a specific sheet name, you can add `ss.getSheetName() == '[Name of the sheet]'` on the [if](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) condition separated by `&` sign, as seen on the sample below:

```
if(ss.getSheetName() == 'Sheet2' & ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 6 & ss.getRange(ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()).getValue() == "OUT"){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Clear all fields to the right.');
  }
```

**Sample Result:**

*If a selected cell on col F is changed from `IN` to `OUT` via a drop-down option:*

[image]

*A pop-up message "Clear all fields to the right." will show on the sheet*

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you for the help and the thorough explination!